# Dynamic validator for TextField / Change validator at runtime

Tags: qt, qml

I have small problem/requirement about validators, which i'm currently not able to implement.

I have a simple TextField (QtQuick.Control 2) which is decorated with different colors depending on a state. It should also use a different RegExpValidator (with another regular expression) depending on the current state.

Does anyone have an idea how i can switch/change/modify a RegExpValidator at runtime? (e.g. when a PushButton is pressed or onEditingFinished-Event is triggered)

My current qml code is:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2 as Quick
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

RowLayout {
    id: layout
    property color modeColor: "whitesmoke"
    property color modeTextColor: "gray"

    spacing: 0
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        Layout.fillWidth: true 
        Layout.minimumWidth: 100 
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        Layout.maximumWidth: 100
        Layout.preferredHeight: layout.implicitHeight
        color: modeColor
        border.width: 1
        border.color: modeColor
        Text {
            id: recttext
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Enter key"
            color: modeTextColor
        }
    }

    Quick.TextField {
        id: input
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        placeholderText: "Text"
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "whitesmoke"
            border.width: 1
            border.color: modeColor
        }
        validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /.*:$/ } 
        onEditingFinished: {
            recttext.text = input.text

            if (layout.state == "keyinput") {
                layout.state = "valinput"
                // should change to another regExp validator
            } else {
                layout.state = "keyinput"
                // should change to another regExp validator
            }
            input.clear()
        }
        Keys.onPressed: {
            if (event.key == Qt.Key_Escape) {
                    layout.state = "keyinput"
                    recttext.text = "Enter key"
                    input.clear()
            }
        }
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "keyinput"
            PropertyChanges { target: layout; modeColor: "whitesmoke"; modeTextColor: "gray" }
        },
        State {
            name: "valinput"
            PropertyChanges { target: layout; modeColor: "red"; modeTextColor: "white" }
        }
    ]
    state: "keyinput"
}
```

Best Regards, Chris

edit: 
The endgoal is an inputline for entering key-value pairs (where i could use a specific RegExpValidator for a specific key.)

Here it should use RegExpValidator for entering a key e.g. "author:" + Pressing Enter (keyinput-mode)
[image: EnterKey]#

After switching into the valueinput-mode, it should use another RegExpValidator:
[image: KeyEntered]

btw. It's a desktop application :)

Comment: What's the end goal? Can you please edit your question to include an example of how user interaction might look with such a UI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this can help you!

```
property var valid1 : IntValidator { bottom:0; top: 2000}
property var valid2 : IntValidator { bottom:2000; top: 4000}

...
validator: if(condition) { valid1 }
else { valid2 }
```

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.